# Сравнение двух массивов python

Tags: python, сортировка

Всем доброго суток, мне надо сравнить два массива, в каждом массиве есть элементы с разбитыми названиями товаров
Как мне сравнить два массива так, что бы нашлись совпадения в названии товаров? Сравнивать надо по слову, можно ли как-то выводить номер элементов в массиве если совпадении в названии допустим 80%
Очень сложно описать задачу, но в моей голове всё как всегда описано идеально.

```
 import packmarket
    import russcarton




def packmarket_func():
    # content_pacmarket = packmarket.main()
    # packmarket_list = [elem.get("name") for elem in content_pacmarket]
    # packmarket_list = [i.split(' ') for i in packmarket_list]
    packmarket_list = [['Гофрокороб', 'Трехслойный', '650x520x220', 'мм'], ['Гофрокороб', 
    'Трёхслойный', '500x250x400'], ['Гофрокороб', 'Трехслойный', '480X480X200', 'мм'], 
    ['Гофрокороб', 'Трехслойный', '380х290х350', 'мм'], ['Гофрокороб', 'Пятислойный', 
    '1000х500х500', 'мм'], ['Гофрокороб', 'Трехслойный', '630х320х340', 'мм'], ['Гофрокороб', 
    'Трехслойный', '500х400х400', 'мм'], ['Картонная', 'коробка', '630х320х340', 'мм', 'с', 
    'ручками'], ['Картонная', 'коробка', '412х310х165', 'мм', 'суперпрочная', ''], ['Картонная', 
    'коробка', '630х320х340', 'мм', 'стандарт', 'бурая'], ['Картонная', 'коробка', '200х150х200', 
    'мм', 'бизнес', 'бурая'], ['Почтовый', 'короб', '425х165х275', 'мм']]
    return packmarket_list

def russcarton_func(): 
    # content_russcarton = russcarton.main()
    # ruscarton_list = [elem.get("name") for elem in content_russcarton]
    # ruscarton_list = [i.replace(',','').split(' ') for i in ruscarton_list]
    ruscarton_list = [['\nКартонная', 'коробка', 'архивная', 'с', 'крышкой', '395х315х270', 'мм', 
    'Т-24', 'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nПочтовый', 'короб', 'тип', '«Д»', '220х165х100', 'мм', 'Т-23', 
    'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '600х400х400', 'мм', 'Т-24', 'бурый', '', 
    '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '600х400х300', 'мм', 'Т-23', 'бурый', '', '\n'], 
    ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '155х155х50', 'мм', 'Т-11', 'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 
    'коробка', '210х140х120', 'мм', 'Т-22', 'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', 
    '180х150х85', 'мм', 'Т-22', 'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', 'архивная', 'А3', 
    '480х325х295', 'мм', 'Т-23', 'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '600х400х400', 
    'мм', 'Т-22', 'бурый', '', '\n'],['\nПочтовый', 'короб', 'тип', '«Ж»', '1-й', 'Класс', 
    '170х120х100', 'мм', 'Т-23', 'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nКороб', '№9', 'архивный', 'А4', 
    '330х230х230', 'мм', 'Т-24', 'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '515х225х150', 
    'мм', 'Т-23', 'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '305х215х160', 'мм', 'Т-22', 
    'бурый', '', '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '500х500х500', 'мм', 'Т-24', 'бурый', '', 
    '\n'], ['\nГардеробный', 'короб', '№15', 'с', 'крышкой', '(большой)', '600х500х1300', 'мм', 
    '', '\n'], ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '300х300х300', 'мм', 'Т-23', 'бурый', '', '\n']]
    return ruscarton_list

def main():
    packmarket_list = packmarket_func()
    ruscarton_list = russcarton_func()
```

Comment: а что в вашем понимании "совпадение 80%"? `кабан` и `кабак` имеют совпадение 80% :)

Comment: Если Вы добавите пример совпадающих, по Вашему мнению, строк, то помочь Вам станет гораздо проще

Comment: Матчинг товаров - это отдельная довольно непростая задача. Ей нужно конкретно заниматься, так с наскоку это не делается. Хотя можете для начала посмотреть куда-то сюда: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Comment: @Zhihar ну вот допустим 2 названия товаров: ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '630х320х340', 'мм', 'Т-24',  '\n'] и  ['Картонная', 'коробка', '630х320х340', 'мм', 'с', 
    'ручками'] тут совпадают 3 слова, допустим это 80%, в таком случае эти 2 товара добавляем с exel файл (но это я уже сам сделаю)

Comment: @Namerek ну вот допустим 2 названия товаров: ['\nКартонная', 'коробка', '630х320х340', 'мм', 'Т-24',  '\n'] и  ['Картонная', 'коробка', '630х320х340', 'мм', 'с', 
    'ручками'] тут совпадают 3 слова, допустим это 80%, в таком случае эти 2 товара добавляем с exel файл (но это я уже сам сделаю)

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать так:

```
res = []

for obj1 in packmarket_list:
    obj1_unique = set(word.lower() for word in obj1 if len(word.strip()) != 0 and word != '\n')

    for obj2 in ruscarton_list:
        obj2_unique = set(word.lower() for word in obj2 if len(word.strip()) != 0 and word != '\n')

        common = obj1_unique & obj2_unique

        if len(common) > len(obj1_unique) * 0.4:
            res.append(obj1)
    
print(*res, sep = '\n')
```

кроме того я привел списки перед сравнением к одинаковому виду - все слова с маленькой буквы, пробелы в начале и конце строки убраны, пустые строки или строки с переводом каретки удалены

а дальше ищется пересечение множеств т.е. общие слова в двух списках)

Единственное, что при критерии 80% не находится совпадений, а вот при критерии 50% находится

**P.S.**

можно также оставить только слова, содержащие буквы

```
obj1_unique = set(word.lower() for word in obj1 if len(word.strip()) != 0 and word != '\n' and word.isalpha())
```

тогда срабатывает уже критерий в 60% :)